# Mask Jquery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mask

Estou tentando usar a mascara do jquery, vou usar ele um *< input >* adicionado pelo javascript pela ação de selecionar um *< option >*.

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
<select name="opcao" id="sel" onchange="muda()" class="form-control">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
</select>
<div class='col-sm-9 text-left' id="rdo">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function muda() {
  if (document.getElementById("sel").value == "option1") {
    document.getElementById('rdo').innerHTML =
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='dia' control-label>Dia</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' type='date' name='dia' id='dia' required autofocus></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='hora' control-label>Hora</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' type='time' name='hora' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='local' control-label>Local</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' size='251' maxlength='250' type='text' name='local' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='endereco' control-label>Endere&ccedil;o</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' maxlength='500' type='text' name='endereco' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='obs' control-label>OBS</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' maxlength='500' type='text' name='obs'></div></div>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('rdo').innerHTML = "";
  }

}
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#dia").mask("99/99/9999")
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que ocorre é devido você adicinar a máscara quando a página é inicializada, porém quando isso ocorre ainda não existe o elemento com o `id="dia"` carregados no documento HTML.

Então como você está adicionando dinamicamente o elemento com `id="dia"` no documento, você também vai ter que adicionar a máscara dinamicamente depois que você adicionar os elementos no documento HTML.

Segue abaixo no exemplo como você pode resolver seu problema:

```js
function muda() {
  if (document.getElementById("sel").value == "option1") {
    document.getElementById('rdo').innerHTML =
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='dia' control-label>Dia</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' type='date' name='dia' id='dia' required autofocus></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='hora' control-label>Hora</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' type='time' name='hora' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='local' control-label>Local</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' size='251' maxlength='250' type='text' name='local' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='endereco' control-label>Endere&ccedil;o</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' maxlength='500' type='text' name='endereco' required></div></div>" +
      "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2' for='obs' control-label>OBS</label><div class='col-sm-9'><input class='form-control' maxlength='500' type='text' name='obs'></div></div>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('rdo').innerHTML = "";
  }
  
  $("#dia").mask("99/99/9999")

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<select name="opcao" id="sel" onchange="muda()" class="form-control">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
</select>

<div class='col-sm-9 text-left' id="rdo">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O jQuery Masked Input foi feito para funcionar com inputs de texto. Você está tentando inserir uma máscara em um campo tipo `date` (que, por si só, não precisa de formatação por trazê-la automaticamente respeitando as regras de padrão de datas baseadas no seu *locale*). Mude o `type` do seu input para `text` que a máscara deve funcionar.